# Error on root's path?

Tags: root

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 and recently I've been getting some weird error on the terminal, I've never seen it before.

Here's a code I entered and received the error:

```
lucas@lucas-pc:~$ sudo apt-get -f install    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
Correcting dependencies... Done    
The following extra packages will be installed:    
  libc-bin    
The following NEW packages will be installed:    
  libc-bin    
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.    
3 not fully installed or removed.    
Need to get 0 B/1.170 kB of archives.    
After this operation, 3.532 kB of additional disk space will be used.    
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y    
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!    
  libc-bin    
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y    
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.    
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.    
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable    
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable    
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I can't really just reinstall Ubuntu because today is exactly the day I installed everything that I needed to work and study!

Does anyone have a solution? Also, considering I just know how to do some things on terminal, but not an expert, could you guys please leave the code?

Answer (score 0):

Something is strange with your system.
The installer complains, that it can not find the binary locale, which is located at /usr/bin/locale, which is packaged in libc-bin, that you are just about to install.

So how did you get rid of libc-bin?
Isn't it installed? Can you run

dpkg -l libc-bin

Comment: That's what I got:  http://i.imgur.com/Ut6MKzP.png

Comment: yes, the package is not installed. It was removed. Hm I would try to copy the file /usr/bin/locale from another system. And see, if you can fix/reinstall libc-bin.